# Comparing two lists / each list compound from 2 columns

Tags: vba, excel

Let's say that I have my personal log in sheet1 and in column "A" i have main number which will be client account number and in column "B" i have their sub accounts number.

In sheet 2 I received accounts and sub accounts list in the same structure and I need to find the unique number which is in sheet2 but I don't have it in my personal log in sheet1.

For example in sheet1 I have

```
account     sub account

1110000     12

1110000     14
```

And i received in sheet2 list which contains:

```
account     sub account

1110000     12

1110000     16
```

The macro should find in this case 1110000     16 (account is the same but sub account is new) from sheet2 list and write it in next empty cell in sheet1.

I'll be very appreciate for your help, I tried with match and vlookup but it doesn't work.

Andrew

Comment: Is it one account number or many?

Comment: Many accounts number with many sub account for each

Comment: How are the account numbers organized? Are they sorted by number? You need to provide more data because of the potential complexity of your macro and scarcity of your data input? I could answer your question with the data you provided but will it do the job for you later? I reckon you will need a `Dictionnary` if you data is not organized.

Comment: The accounts are always sorted out from smallest to largest number. On the list are always numeric values, Usually I have in my log in column "A" all accounts number which are on the list which i received, more often i need to catch up the sub number connected to the account which i already had.
There are two possibilities:
a) I have account number but i don't have a new sub number
b)I don't have account and sub number

Main problem is to automatize it, that macro will check accounts and if the account exist check sub numbers this account (if account doesn't exist write account and sub number)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One possible solution is to copy accounts and sub-accounts of your log sheet into an array. Do the same with accounts and sub-accounts in sheet2. Then loop through all couples of account and sub-account from sheet2 and test if they are in the log array. If not copy them into an array of new accounts. At the end copy new accounts into your log sheet. Below the code for this solution:

```
Option Explicit
Option Base 1

Sub CopyNewAccountsInLogSheet()

Dim initial As Range 'range with accounts and sub-accounts in sheet 1
Dim destination As Range 'the range where to add new accounts and sub-accounts in sheet1
Dim myLog() As Variant 'array with accounts and sub-accounts from log sheet
Dim newList() As Variant 'array of accounts and sub-accounts from sheet 2
Dim newAccounts() As Variant 'array of accounts and sub-accounts to add to log sheet
Dim x, y, n As Integer
Dim isInLog As Boolean

Set initial = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("a1").CurrentRegion 'replace with correct range
Set destination = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A" & (initial.Rows.Count + 1)) 'first cell below initial range
myLog = initial.Value
newList = Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("a1").CurrentRegion.Value 'replace with correct range
ReDim newAccounts(UBound(newList, 1), 2)
n = 0

For x = 1 To UBound(newList, 1) 'loop through new list

    isInLog = False 'by default, we assume account + sub-account is not in log sheet

    For y = 1 To UBound(myLog, 1) 'compare with each account + sub-account in log file
        If CStr(myLog(y, 1)) & CStr(myLog(y, 2)) = CStr(newList(x, 1)) & CStr(newList(x, 2)) Then
            isInLog = True
            Exit For
        End If
    Next

    If Not isInLog Then
        n = n + 1
        newAccounts(n, 1) = newList(x, 1)
        newAccounts(n, 2) = newList(x, 2)
    End If

Next

If n > 0 Then destination.Resize(n, 2).Value = newAccounts 'copy new accounts in sheet

End Sub
```

Comment: Super great!!! It's working. Thank you very very much for your help and effort !!